# Edit Matrix in ReportViewer Using Code in Vb

Tags: database, vb.net, matrix, reportviewer

I have this in my DataBase :

Table Days:

```
IdDay  NameDay   
1      Monday     
2      Tuesday
3      Wednesday
4      Thursday
5      Friday
6      Saturday
7      Sunday
```

Table Time:

```
IdTime  Time
 1       9am
 2       10am
 3       11am
```

Table Work:

```
IdWork   NameWork   IdDay IdTime
1        cleaning   6      3
2        Studying   1      2
```

I am trying to edit a `Matrix` in My `ReportViewer`:

```
Day      [Time]
[NameDay]
```

I want to use code and edit my `Matrix` like  this `Algo` :

```
if database day = day in the matrix && database Time= time in matrix 
   Put NameWork
```

Is there a way to do that ?